# Run function from pointer within c program

Tags: c, linux, fork

Is there any way to run a program and/or file from within a running c program using a file pointer, or would one have to use the normal file name and system/fork etc? If it matters, writing this on linux.

Essentially, I'm asking if something like this is possible:

```
FILE * fp=fopen("somefile")
//dostuff
```

run the file pointed to by fp here (with fp, not with the filename)

Comment: Do you have any [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to run a program and/or file from within a running c
>   program using a file pointer

It is not really clear what you are asking so I'll try to show you some of the way you can do it.

Maybe you're talking about [`execve()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

where `execve()` executes the program pointed to by filename and `argv` is an array of argument strings passed to the new program. Similarly there is [`fexecve()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fexecve) that works the same as `execve()` with the difference that the file to be executed is specified via a file descriptor, `fd`, rather than via a pathname.

Or, you can use [`system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) for running some program. For example:

```
int result = system("./myProgram 2 3");
```

This will wait for *myProgram* to be executed, then will get the exitcode.

Last but not least, you can use [`fork()`](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html) a system call used to create processes.